# Understanding iptables rate limit

Tags: iptables

I am new to iptables and I was trying to make sure I understand this statement.

```
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 5.5.5.5 --dport 25 -m limit --limit 20/min --limit-burst 25 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 5.5.5.5 --dport 25 -j DROP
```

If an address connects to 5.5.5.5 more than 25 times in 20 minutes block that ip?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Maybe try it on a network administration forum?

Answer (score 4):

You're close. This isn't on a TCP-connection level, it's on a packet level. To deal with connections instead of packets - you'd want to use the state module.

See: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/187/Using_iptables_to_rate-limit_incoming_connections

The negotiation of TCP connections alone is already many packets. See: http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml

These 2 rules state - for all ethernet devices -> if protocol is tcp, destination ip address is 5.5.5.5, and destination port is 25 limit incoming packets to 20 per minute with a burstable amount of an additional 25 per minute. Drop any over this limit.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page): it will block multiple failed connections. It works for SSH and can be configured for other protocols.